# How can I change `All Desired` properties of the windows controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm using WinForms : C# .NET.

I'm facing a problem with `ContextMenuStrip`  and `Toolstrip`. Visual Stuido's Property editor is not letting me to change the property I want.

Here is the snapshot of how I want my `ContextMenuStrip` to looklike & same is the case with `Toolstrip`. I don't understand how to do this.

If I need to learn something, please suggest appropriate good material (tutorials, articles etc.)

[alt text http://f.imagehost.org/0289/KproxyChecker.jpg](http://f.imagehost.org/0289/KproxyChecker.jpg)

Comment: I don't see a snapshot, what is the property you cannot change?

Comment: http://f.imagehost.org/0289/KproxyChecker.jpg

Comment: I guess it's my corporate filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single property that you can set to make a `ContextMenuStrip` look like that.

You need to create your own [`ToolStripRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.aspx) class that paints menus like that, then set the [`Renderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer.aspx) property of the ContextMenuStrip to an instance of your `ToolStripRenderer`.

Good luck.

**EDIT**: You can find sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.aspx#exampleToggle).

Comment: Does every control have this kind of rendering? In that case, How to find which its renderer class?  Because I want to change color scheme of all the controls. 1. Window's Title Bar & Border Color 2. The skyblue shade in the Toolstrip  etc..

Comment: No; only ToolStrip.  You can paint the titlebar your self by overriding WndProc and handling the WM_NCPAINT message.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Comment: You should probably switch to a component suite with built-in skinning support; it will be _much much_ easier than doing it yourself.  I recommend DevExpress.  http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/

Comment: This seems to be WIN32API. I'm using .NET. :(

Comment: I'm not developing this application for commercial purposes. I'm doing this to learn to make custom GUI & custom controls . So, if you could show me some way to doing it myself I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to assign the Renderer property to a class that renders the CMS or tool strip the way you want it.  Use this code as a template to get started:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new myRenderer();
    }
    class myRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        protected override void OnRenderToolStripBackground(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e) {
            // Replace this with your own drawing code...
            base.OnRenderToolStripBackground(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to know whenever you guys give the sample code. Do you guys code it for the answer or It will be from your previous work?

Comment: Don't hold it against me, please.  I typed it in 10 minutes ago to make sure it compiled.

Comment: I really appreciate when people give some sample code. Thank you. :)